# Communicating through two separate computer using java sockets

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to make a chat server and client that can communicate over two separate computers connected to the internet. One of them is connected to wifi and another one is through a modem. Here is my server code.

GreetingServer.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int port = Integer.parseInt("6066");
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

GreetingClient.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient2
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String serverName = "10.2.3.100";
      int port = Integer.parseInt("6066");
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName +
         " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to " 
         + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

The IP address in Client code is of the computer where the server is running acquired by InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(). When I run the server, it waits for the client. And when I run the client code from another computer, it doesn't connect. Is it possible to communicate like this through sockets in java ?

Comment: if both are in the same network, or if one network is being routed to another, I guess so

Comment: `String serverName = "10.2.3.100";` Could you please provide a `ifconfig`input please ?

Comment: I guess the server computer has a disabled firewall on the port 6066 ?

Comment: Try a `traceroute` from the client to the server, it may reveal problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Your server has to have an [external ip](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/externip.htm).

Also if your server is connected via WiFi, check router firewall settings.

Comment: I don't think so. I already did in in a local network, so all the IP were in the same address range.

Comment: It works fine when run from separate computers. But it throws an excepting saying "Connection refused : connect" when I run both server and client on the same computer using external IP. But it is fine when I use localhost. Why is this happening ?